# How to detect key-guard state in android

Tags: android, android-service

I have an application that requires to detect the previous state of the key-guard before calling `disableKeyguard()` or `reenableKeyguard()`, set by the user! is there any way of accomplishing this task?

Comment: isKeyguardLocked() ? - from KeyGuardManager

Comment: That is exactly what I want...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html)

Use

```
((KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE)).isKeyguardLocked()
```

Comment: I declare the `KeyguardManager` inside a service and it does not show any method like this `isKeyguardLocked()`

Comment: isKeyguardLocked() is a method of KeyguardManager, so you should see it.  Maybe your getSystemService() is the problem because you are not calling it from an Activity?  If that's the case then do KeyguardManager myManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE)); from the activity and pass it to the service when you construct it. Then from the service call isKeyguardLocked. If you can't do this post some code :)

Comment: Is there a method for API < 16 , too?